# Why do Decision Trees/rpart prefer to choose continuous over categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, cart, rpart

I run some decision trees in `rpart` with 10 continuous variables and 3 categorical variables (with 1 or 0 options), the result of the tree was that none of the 3 categorical variables were used in building the trees. Do you know if maybe there is a deficiency combining data from continuous and categorical variables for decision trees?

Comment: Could it be that the categorical variables aren't relevant once you've accounted for the continuous variables?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, classical decision tree algorithms - e.g., CART (as implemented in `rpart`) or C4.5 - are biased towards variables with many possible splits. The reason is that they use exhaustive search over all possible splits in all possible variables without accounting for finding larger improvements by "chance" when searching over more splits. This is addressed by various decision tree algorithms based on statistical inference, pioneered by Loh and co-workers:

- Loh WY, Shih YS (1997). "Split Selection Methods for Classification 
  Trees." *Statistica Sinica*, **7**, 815-840.
- Loh WY (2002). "Regression Trees with Unbiased Variable Selection and
  Interaction Detection." *Statistica Sinica*, **12**, 361-386.
- Hothorn T, Hornik K, Zeileis A (2006). "Unbiased Recursive Partitioning:
  A Conditional Inference Framework." *Journal of Computational and
  Graphical Statistics*, **15**(3), 651-674.

In R the `partykit` package (successor to the `party` package) implements several unbiased decision tree algorithms. Specifically, `ctree()` (Hothorn *et al.* 2006) should be easy to try for you as an alternative for `rpart`.

Having said that: It is, of course, possible that even when using an unbiased decision tree algorithm none of the categorical variables appear in the tree because they are not relevant (or not relevant after adjusting for the continuous ones as suggested by @gung).

Comment: Does the tendency to bias towards a multi-level categorical variable get worse or better if this variable is converted using one-hot encoding to multiple binary variables?

Comment: If you encode a multi-level categorical variable to _all_ possible binary variables, then the results are unchanged because the same number of splits is offered and searched. However, if the encoding used reduces the number of possible splits (as in the one-hot case, if I understand you correctly) then the selection bias should get worse - simply because there are less possible splits with respect to the original multi-level variable.

Comment: Yes, if categorical variable has K levels, then one-hot encoding will create K binary variables (a lot less than the 2^(K-1)-1 splits you could make on the original variable). But I'm not sure I follow your logic: I thought the selection bias happens because there are so many splits possible that some might fit well just by chance. So if we *reduce* the number of splits allowed, shouldn't the selection bias be reduced as well?

Comment: Well, it depends on the size of K. If you have a small K (say 6) but N=1000 then a truly continuous variable will offer many more possible splits than the categorical variable. Hence, the selection will prefer the former. Reducing the number of splits considered in the categorical variable will amplify this contrast. However, if K=20 the picture would be different, of course. Then you would go from an artifical preference of the categorical variable to an artificial preference of the numeric variable. (But categorical covariates with so many levels can also be problematic for other reasons.)